# Navigation element don't see Fragments

Tags: android

I have a project with Fragments and Activities. I want to try Navigation element, but I can't add Fragments on my graph - in the destination list, I have only Activities. Why does it happen?

Androidx, Java.

UPD: I can't find the correct tag for this navigation element, so only the `Android` tag present.

Gragle:

```
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0"
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The screen where I have no Fragments on the destination list:

[image: Screen of my Fragment]

And, I think it can be important, my preview of MainActivity:

[image: Preview of MainActivity]

I don't know why, but it gray.
UPD1: red mark on last screen is:

```
A <fragment> tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.
```

I think it's explain why my fragment grey on preview - layout is unknown on runtime. So, my problem is not connecting with it.

Comment: Have you checked the red exclamation mark in the top right corner which is supposedly indicating that you have a warning/error that may or may not be causing your problem?

Comment: Ty, i read red mark exclamation and update my question. Unfortunately there is no connection between this and my problem.

Comment: `tools:layout="@layout/fragment1"` on the `<fragment` tag can help, although the fragment destinations not showing up really is a separate issue. Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: It helps to see my fragment layout, ty. =)
I think the main problem is about project, i create new project with several fragments and all works. BUt current project too large to migrate him this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's resolve itselfs when i create one fragment by hands on my navigation graph, and do "Invalidate/restart".

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you have to add ***tools:layout*** line to your fragment tag:  `tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sample_name"`

It should looks like this in navigation graph code view

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/sampleFragment"
        android:name="com.example.sampleFragment"
        android:label="@string/sample_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sample">
 </fragment>
```

Be sure *navigation tag* have `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` added

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_sample_stackoverflow"
    app:startDestination="@id/sampleFragment">
```